# Which is better for my Git project, submodules or subtree

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have a service I'm developing that will be made up of multiple 'bits'. It's going to be open source so I want to make it easy for people to see the project as a whole, check it out, make changes etc., rather than give people a list of different projects to check out.

So imagine I have a project called 'Flintstones' and it is made of 'Barney', 'Wilma' and 'Bambam'.

As far as I understand if I did this with subtrees then if a person checks out 'Flintstones' they see everything, but if they make a change to code in Barney they have to merge that code back to the Barney repository. So thats bad because people will change code and either not know about it being a sub tree or just not do it.

All the sub module examples talk about them being used to embed common code in a project, but am I right saying if a person checks out 'Flintstones' and makes a change in the 'Barney' folder, then just does a regular commit and push then that change goes to Barney? Is the only downside in this scenario that they have to check the project out with extra syntax to checkout submodules?

I want to split it out so that builds are only triggered and carried out for the part of the project that changed, so changes to Barney result in only Barney being built and tested on my CI server (bamboo in this case). In time different people will work on different modules of the code without having to even know about the others.

Comment: How is this opinion? I have outlined a scenario and want to know which approach is designed to fit this. Edited to remove the 'evil' comment

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's asking for a subjective opinion. The poster has outlined his requirements and is asking which of the two approaches he's mentioned will work best for him. Voting to reopen.

Comment: YET ANOTHER legitimate question that has been SHUT DOWN where qualified input from the community - opinion or not - is extremely valuable.  It's pretty amazing to see a group of sharp guys like SO double down again and again and again and again and again on their ill conceived "no discussion" policy.  I, for one, have supported that policy by moving my business first to GitHub than to StackOverflow if I cant find what I want on GitHub.  I only post now when I want to throw a jab like this one.  To SO:  Don't give up! Keep those users in submission!!